# drawableLeft vector image api < 21 from XML

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable, xml-drawable

I have support lower end device API < 21. I already have used drawableLeft, drawableRight in many place in my existing project. When ever I am running API 19 app is crashing saying can't find that image.

I know I can add the image programmatically, but in this case I have to update whole project. Is there any solution to solve it?

I am using `buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"`

> NOTE: As I already have more than 50+ vector not possible to edit one by one like adding :

```
layer-list
```

Answer (score 0):

**From 23.3.0 version vector drawables can only be loaded via app:srcCompat or setImageResource()**

Create a separate drawable with layer list **new_icon.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_vector_drawable" />
</layer-list>
```

Now in your TextView set it using follows

```
<TextView
...
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/new_icon"/>
```

Comment: Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/xyz/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
 at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:380)

Comment: can you clean and rebuild the project

Comment: happen after adding :                 android:drawableLeft="@{@drawable/ic_person_outline_black_24dp}"

Comment: in your project go to app -> build and delete all folders present there. now clean prjoect and test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183633/discussion-between-anirban-and-karan-mer).

Comment: As I mentioned I have more than 50+ vector I don't want to create layer-list for every vector.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a case that your images are in a folder like `drawable-v24` and not in the main `drawable` folder?  
If this is the case then copy them to `drawable` too.  
Otherwise they cannot be found.

Comment: No all are in drawable, by the way vector image will automatically create inside drawable folder if you use android studio to create it.

Comment: If you see the drawables in `Android` view they seem all to be in the `drawable` folder but if they have a suffix like `(v24)` then they are not. Change to `Project` view and check them.

Comment: I have opened it in project view not andorid

Answer (score 0):

In your app's **build.gradle** you need to include:

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
}
```

And for vector support for less then API 21, add the following to `onCreate`:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```